# The source attachment does not contain the source for the file SunPKCS11.class

Tags: java, eclipse

I want to debug my application that is using SunPCKS11 class. Oracle's JDK doesn't come with sources for PKCS11 libraries, so I downloaded the OpenJDK source for that class from [github](https://github.com/frohoff/jdk8u-dev-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/sun/security/pkcs11/SunPKCS11.java).

However, when I attach sources from that file, Eclipse doesn't recognize it and gives me "The source attachment does not contain the source for the file SunPKCS11.class".

I also tried downloading the whole PKCS11 sources folder and packaged it in JAR. The directory structure in JAR looks like this: sun/security/PKCS11, but again, when I attach the JAR as a source it isn't recognized by Eclipse.

Note that I still use Oracle's JDK, not OpenJDK. I just want to use sources from OpenJDK.

Does anyone know how acually Eclipse recognize source files and decide if the source is valid?

Comment: Is it under Windows? In the Windows package you can choose whether to have sources installed. There are some unspecified differences between OpenJDK and Oracle's JDK. This could be one of them.

Comment: Yes, it's Windows. But I didn't understand your question completely. Yes, I have sources installed as I installed Oracle's JDK not JRE. But, it turned out that Oracle's JDK doesn't contain the sources for PKCS libraries. That's why I'm trying to force Eclipse use the OpenJDK's soruce

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer my own question. I made a mistake by putting the sources I downloaded to `sun/security` instead of `sun/security/pkcs11`. And the package name of the class I was trying to debug is `package sun.security.pkcs11` so I needed to have the right folder structure which answers my second question:

Eclipse looks for sources by searching for the source file in folder structure that corresponds to the fully qualified class name.